# Application Forces to close when I start another activity through Intent and display a text

Tags: setcontentview

App Force closes when I try to start this intent and display the text I have already included the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_try_text);`

```
public class TryText extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_try_text);
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        text.setText("hi");

    }
}
```

And here is the logcat

06-30 12:03:05.115: I/Process(698): Sending signal. PID: 698 SIG: 9
06-30 12:03:11.802: D/AndroidRuntime(1327): Shutting down VM
06-30 12:03:11.802: W/dalvikvm(1327): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b7bd40)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): Process: com.example.bag, PID: 1327
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bag/com.example.bag.TryText}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3561)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:299)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1957)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:220)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:106)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:81)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.example.bag.TryText.onCreate(TryText.java:21)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
06-30 12:03:11.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
setContentView(text);
```

As you have already inflated your View.

If that doesn't work, post your logcat.

Hope it helps